# Socket.io sending too many requests (React)

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, socket.io

I'm building a small chat app using React, Node, and Socket.io. Every time I do something in the React page (type a letter) a request gets sent from Socket.io (although it's not coming from the React code).

[Requests](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hRq1s.png)

I read in other questions that this is expected behaviour, but there're so many requests that the app always gets stuck at some point. How can I stop this and why does it happen?

[Server file (Node.js)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BL5AA.png)

[React file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6kP2j.png)

Comment: It's unlikely anyone can help you with only screenshots of a small amount of code.  Questions here should include all the relevant code related to the question and that code should be pasted into the question and formatted as text.   No screenshots of code because people can't then copy/paste it into answers, it isn't searchable and it isn't very accessible (to screen readers or other such tools).

Comment: A wild guess is here: [Socket.io keeps connecting repeatedly and ignores other events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48069633/socket-io-keeps-connecting-repeatedly-and-ignores-other-events/48071324#48071324).